# Python - Print whole calendar of a specific year (without importing calendar)

Tags: python, function, calendar

could somebody help me at creating a function(day, month, year) which later prints every date of the year.
-> 01.01.2000

02.01.2000

....

31.12.2000

I already have the functions nextDay (the day after the current date) and YearDays (amount of days in the year).

I don't know how to do this since I'm new to Python. 
Thank you.

Comment: I either get just one or 365 times the same date :/

Comment: Please post your code here. We have no idea what `nextDay` and `YearDays` look like.

Comment: may i ask. why?

Comment: What do you mean "without importing calendar"? Can you use `datetime`?

Answer (score 3):

you can do it using datetime and timedelta 
maybe something like that :

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def all_days(day, month, year):
   d = date(year, month, day)
   while d.year == year:
      yield d
      d += timedelta(days = 1)

for d in all_days(07,12,2016):
   print(d)
```